# Create intent on click WebView link

Tags: android, android-webview

Ok, there will be two types of links in the content of my WebView. The behavior will be defined by the format of the link.

```
(1) Open the link in a browser. (The url begins with "openbrowser:")
(2) According to the link, open another Activity in the same project. 
(The url will be "openactivity")
```

I am not sure if it is possible to create a map for the WebView which maps from a url pattern to an intent. For example, by default, if the url begins with "mailto:" the WebView will create an intent to open the mailbox. Could I define other mappings for my WebView?

I know there is a way to set a WebViewClient and override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method. But in API level 19, the function is not guaranteed to be called:

[shouldOverrideUrlLoading() not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298290/webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-not-called-for-invalid-links)

So is it possible to set this url pattern to intent mapping as a general settings of the WebView?

Comment: I'm using this approach (custom schema) with Kit Kat devices and haven't encountered any problems. Have you tested it?

Comment: In my case, the data to be displayed in WebView is returned from the server as an HTML string. So I am going to load the data with:contentWebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8"). I am not sure if this is your case.

Comment: That's exactly our case. See the sample in the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a WebViewClient should be enough. We've had no problems with API level 19. For example:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
String html = "<html><body><a href=\"showmessage:hello%20there\">Test it</a></body></html>";
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.startsWith("showmessage"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```