# shouldOverrideUrlLoading() not called for external links from iframe

Tags: android, android-webview

Although issues with shouldOverrideUrlLoading() are well discussed in SO (I probably read most of them), I still didn't find a solution to what seems to me such a generic problem, that I believe has been solved.

The QUESTION: How to stop in shouldOverrideUrlLoading() for external links, e.g. "http://www.example.com", for pages I loaded with webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(), where baseUrl is "file:///..."?

My override method for shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called when external links are touched (clicked).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298290/webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-not-called-for-invalid-links) it says " URLs that can't be resolved against the base URL are dropped on the floor (you won't get any callbacks for them, neither shouldOverrideUrlLoading nor onPageStarted)."
Android developer site says [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs) that "If you loaded the page by calling ... loadDataWithBaseURL(), then you will receive the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() callback **for this type of link on the page**." 
This is my code:

```
public void loadEpub(final EpubInfo epubInfo)
{
    post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            epubBaseUrl = "file://" + epubInfo.path;
            if (!epubBaseUrl.endsWith("/"))
                epubBaseUrl += "/";

            String path = epubBaseUrl + epubInfo.baseUrl;
            String page = generatePage(epubInfo);
            EpubWebView.super.loadDataWithBaseURL(path, page, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        }
    });
}
```

where my baseUrl (path) is "file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/...".

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinpointed the problem, and found a solution.
If your page runs in an `iframe`, clicking on external (http://www...) links does NOT trigger `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`! Unless you add `target="_top"`
So there are at least 2 possible solutions: 
1) if you can,  run without an `iframe` 
2) if you add to each `href`, `target="_top"`, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` WILL BE triggered.

I went for solution 2). The following `JavaScript` code adds the target attribute to each link.

```
function change_links_target()
{   
    var all_document_links = mFrameDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < all_document_links.length; i++){
        all_document_links[i].setAttribute("target", "_top");
    }
}
```