# Android WebView Links Does not Open

Tags: android, webview

How can I click on a link that is provided in the WebView data that I load?

The WebView data that is load is in HTML format as:

```
<P CLASS="western" ALIGN=JUSTIFY STYLE="margin-bottom: 0.14in">Further
<A HREF="google.com">here</A></P>
```

The WebView is placed inside a scroll view and its webClient is as:

```
webViewClient = new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url)
            {
            }
        };

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tos);                                 // Defining the WebView for the terms and conditions and loading the required data
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.loadData(getResources().getString(R.string.terms_of_service), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

The problem is that when I click on the Link no action takes place. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Debug and ensure that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` should called.The link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298290/webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-not-called-for-invalid-links

Comment: @GiruBhai its not called

Answer (score 0):

use this code to open

```
WebView webView;//make sure to initialize  
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

WebViewClient webViewClient= new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
        if( url.equals("http://yoururl.com") ){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check the url value inside `onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url)` method... it will show what url you are calling on click